# web api - assign model at runtime to action

Tags: c#, dynamic, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, mef

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser(UserModel model)
        {

            //do something

            return Ok();
        }
```

I have a user model to be passed as a POST request for my API.
Is it possible to assign the UserModel at runtime. The reason being, I want to keep the **UserModel** dynamic (in a separate pluggable dll) for different implementation for the same API call.

Also similar situation for the following GET:

```
public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
        {
            return new UserInfoViewModel
            {
                //fill the data
            };
        }
```

Similar dyanamic behaviour is needed for **UserInfoViewModel**

Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking here. Do you want to have multiple versions of this method taking different types that are MEF imported from another assembly? Who will implement the "do something", is that in the other DLLs as well or will each of the UserModel type objects look the same so you could reuse the code that you write here?

Comment: @TomOrton, Thanks. Actually the method will be same for different implementations. But I am trying if I can use different data model for different implementation and installation as a custom model. Is this possible? I can write a separate plugin of how this model can be used. But is this possible to accept a different data model without using a dynamic model.

Comment: If the method will be the same, couldn't you use an interface or base class instead?

Comment: @TomOrton Then, how do I associate my different models with these interface or base class. The DIs or MEF work with constructor or property injection. How can I do that with Web API Action methods. And is it possible to modify the help file to reflect the relevant json object.

Comment: I don't understand the question... To relate the parameter class to the base class you would inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a dynamic object for the model if you don't want to give it a concret object.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostUser(dynamic model)
```